# Angular 4: Request getting cancelled in browser but works in postman

Tags: javascript, angular, http, httpclient

Iam trying to make a POST call from my anguar 4 app. The request is getting cancelled on Browser. However when i copy the same request in postman it works perfectly.

**Request - /logout (POST), with empty body in request - {}**

Response :

```
{
   code: 200,
   message: 'Logout successfully'
}
```

Below is how iam resolving the post request

```
this.signinService.signOut().subscribe((data) => {
      if (data && data.response == 1) {
        localStorage.clear();
        this.cookieService.remove(AppSettings.cookieName, { path: '/', secure: AppSettings.secure });
        this.cookieService.remove(AppSettings.refreshCookieName, { path: '/', secure: AppSettings.secure });
      }
    });
```

I have also tried to check if there is a CORS issue and there's no issue on that front.

**Signout Method in service**

```
public signOut(): Observable<any> {
    return this.HttpService.post('v2/logout', {});
 }
```

**HttpService**

```
 public post<T>(url: string, params: Object, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<T> {

    if (options && options.apiServer)
      url = `${AppSettings[options.apiServer]}/${url}`;
    else
      url = `${AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT}/${url}`;

    return this.http.post<T>(url, params, options).take(1).catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      return Observable.throw(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the `signOut()` function? It seems relevant.

Comment: @ChrisG Edited the question to incorporate Signout method.
It basically calls httpservice wrapper and in that wrapper. we have used htttpclient's post method to POST a request.